# SKShapeNode subclass

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I'm trying to use subclass to create SKShapeNode.

But in draw() function I'm using self.scene property which is nil, why?

When I move whole code to GameScene file, it works.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

let blocksCount: Int

init(size: CGSize, level: Int) {
    self.blocksCount = (level + 2) * 2
    super.init(size: size)
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    run(SKAction.run(addOuterMovingBlocks))
} 
 
private func addOuterMovingBlocks() {
        let shape = ExternalRingNode()
        shape.setup(number: 1)

        addChild(shape)
}
} 
 

class ExternalRingNode: SKShapeNode {

override init() {
    super.init()
}

func setup(number: Int) {
    path = draw(number).cgPath
}

func draw(_ number: Int) -> UIBezierPath {
    guard let scene = scene as? GameScene else { return }
    
    return UIBezierPath()
}
}
```

Comment: What does 'return UIBezierPath()' mean?

Comment: It means nothing, I have to reduce code because stack don't want to public post. 
originally this function looks like:

Comment: `func draw(_ number: Int) -> UIBezierPath {`
`guard let scene = scene else { return UIBezierPath() }` 
`let endDegree = 360.0 / Double(number)` 
`let end = CGFloat(endDegree).toRadians()`    
`let path = UIBezierPath()`     
`path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: scene.radius() * 1.5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)`    
`path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: scene.radius() * 2.5, startAngle: end, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)`    
`path.close()`   
`return path`    
`}`.

Comment: I've only looked at this quickly, but a couple of questions : 1) Do you need to reference the scene in the subclass? 2) If it works when internal but not external, that implies that it's something about the scope of `GameScene`, so if your subclass does need the scene, could you pass the scene as a parameter?